# In tmux, how can I replace the current session by selecting another and killing the current one?

Tags: tmux

I would like a Tmux command that is similar to `choose-session` (`PREFIX s`) but kills the current session if another is selected.

Ideally the command would detach the current session if it was attached elsewhere but kill it if this was the only attachment. This can be discovered with `tmux display -p '#{session_many_attached}'`

---

there is a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58588) but it's quite old and asks the question in reverse (query, kill, connect).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This binds `PREFIX C-s` to choose a session, switch to it and then kill the prior session:

```
bind-key C-s \
  if-shell "(($(tmux display -p '#{session_many_attached}') > 0))" \
    choose-session \
    "run-shell \"tmux choose-session \\\"switch-client -t '%%'; kill-session -t '$(tmux display -p '#S')'\\\"\""
```

I've used shell expressions (*another answer that did not use the shell would be great!*). First I use Tmux's `if-shell` to decide whether there are multiple attached clients. If there are then I just invoke the standard `choose-session` command.

However, if this is the only client attached to the session, I pass a custom command to `choose-session` but I do it in shell (with `run-shell`) so that I can build the command-line passed to `choose-session`.

That command-line is built of two commands:

- `switch-client -t '%%'` which is what `choose-session` uses by default (see `man tmux` for an explanation).
- `kill-session -t '$(tmux display -p '#S')'` first uses a subshell to get the name of the *current* session (it hasn't yet been destroyed) and passes that as a parameter to `kill-session`.

The final command requires lots of escaping to make it work. The `if-shell` takes three arguments: a shell command and two tmux commands. These need to be quoted if they contain whitespace. Therefore, the third argument `run-shell...` is quite nasty!

*(tmux 2.3)*

Comment: Very cool answer! I'm using fish as shell and so I had to change $(tmux display ...) by (tmux display ...).

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! Just for clarification: to make the keybinding work it has to be put into `~/.tmux.conf` and then tmux has to be restarted.